# How to grep two lines from lshw?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to grep the motherboard serial number and the product model of a computer. I used

```
sudo lshw | grep -m1  serial:
```

to grep the serial number (since there are multiple occurrences of "serial:" and the one I want is the first one. How can I do this AND simultaneously grep for "product:" as well? There are also multiple occurrences of product, and the first one is again the one I want.

`lshw` returns this:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw
ubuntu-pc              
    description: Notebook
    product: 23252DG (LENOVO_MT_2325)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: ThinkPad X230
    serial: R9TWZVR
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=notebook family=ThinkPad X230 power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_2325 uuid=01ECC0B1-8251-CB11-8538-B7D9EC435D9B
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 23252DG
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Defined
       serial: 1ZPAB2AC2C1
       slot: Not Available
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
          serial: None
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want the first two lines that match either `product:` or `serial:`. If so, you can try:

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -Em2 'serial:|product:'
    product: 20FWCTO1WW (LENOVO_MT_20FW_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad T460p)
    serial: PF0P1EUH
```

Alternatively, `grep` all lines that match either of the target strings and then use `head` to only print the 1st two:

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -E 'serial:|product:' | head -n2
    product: 20FWCTO1WW (LENOVO_MT_20FW_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad T460p)
    serial: PF0P1EUH
```

Of course, both of these approaches assume that you will never have a second `product:` before the first `serial:` and vice versa.

Answer (score 15):

Use `lshw` with the `--class` or `-c` switch to show only the `system` class and you don't need to worry about extracting only the 1st occurrence:

```
lshw -c system | grep -E 'product:|serial:'
```

If you don't want to use `-c system` you could use `sed` and `q`uit on 1st occurrence of `serial`:

```
lshw | sed '/serial/q;/product/!d'
```

If you need only the values you could use `jq`:

```
lshw -json -c system | jq '.product,.serial'
```

---

<sup>Assuming you're running those commands as root.</sup>

Comment: Nice! Out of curiosity, how did you know to use `system`? I don't see it mentioned in `man lshw`. Can we be confident that `-c system` will always show the motherboard details and nothing else?

Comment: @terdon - it's in the manual: if you run `lshw -short` (to see the hardware classes) the output is self-explanatory

Comment: Ah, so it is, thanks. Apparently, I only read the first sentence of the `-c` section in the manual and missed the second which explained precisely that. *Sigh*.

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep` and `-class` option:

```
sudo lshw -class system | grep 'product\|serial'
```